# Dynamically Adding/Deleting Rows using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to add/delete rows dynamically.

The jQuery code is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 1;
    $('#add_row').click(function() {
        $('#addr' + i).html("<td>&nbsp;" + (i + 1) + "&nbsp;</td><td><input class='tbl_text' maxlength='250' name='invoiceNo[]' size='25' style='text-transform:uppercase' type='search' required /></td><td><input class='date' max='2099-12-31' name='date[]' onkeydown='return false' type='date' required /></td><td><input class='tbl_text' maxlength='500' name='desc[]' size='50' type='search' required /></td><td><input class='amt' name='amt[]' step='0.01' type='number' required /></td>");
        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
        i++;
    });

    $('#delete_row').click(function() {
        if (i > 0) {
            $('#addr' + i).remove();
            calculateSum();
            i--;
        }
    });
});
```

The HTML is as below:

```
    <table align="center" border="1" class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic" style="border:2px solid black;border-collapse:collapse">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="25" />&nbsp;
<th>Invoice No.</th>
<th>Invoice Date</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Amount S$<br>(Including GST)</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr id='addr0'>
<td>&nbsp;1&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><input class="tbl_text" maxlength="250" name="invoiceNo[]" size="25" style="text-transform:uppercase" type="search" required /></td>
<td align="center"><input class="date" max="2099-12-31" name="date[]" onkeydown="return false" type="date" required /></td>
<td align="center"><input class="tbl_text" maxlength="500" name="desc[]" size="50" type="search" required /></td>
<td align="center"><input class="amt" id="amt" name="amt[]" step="0.01" type="number" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr id='addr1'></tr>
</tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="5" height="5" style="border:none;" />
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" colspan="5" height="50" style="border:none;"><button class="button" id="add_row" type="button">Add Row</button><span style='display:inline-block;width:1em;'>&nbsp;</span><button class="button_cancel" id="delete_row" type="button">Delete Row</button><span style='display:inline-block;width:0.5em;'>&nbsp;</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5" height="5" style="border:none;" />
</tr>
<tr height="50" id="summation">
<td class="label" colspan="4">&nbsp;Total Amount Payable</td>
<td align="right" class="label"><span id="sum">$0.00</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It is working but sometimes, I need to click the button twice before the function is performed & sometimes I only need to click once.

Am I missing anything? Any advise please, thanks.

Comment: could you show your html code?

Comment: when you delete row, you delete always the last row?

Comment: You shouldn't use `click` directly, but `$(document).on("click", "#addr" + i, function() {...});`, which is the proper way for jQuery to catch events on items in the DOM.

Comment: @Romainbiard OP isn't clicking #addr+i, they're clicking a (at a guess) single #delete_row - without HTML, impossible to tell, but it's not in the .html provided

Comment: @Frenchy it's very confusing - on add_row, they add to an existing row (assuming one exists) then add a new blank row without any cells - on delete_row they delete the last, empty/no cells row.  Looks like `$("#tab_logic").append` needs to be before the `$("#addr"+i).html` - with correspnding `i` / `(i+1)` fixes.  Then it'll all work.   Personally, I'd put the delete on the row otherwise, even if it worked, it would still always delete from the last row.